# php - store image on server best way

Tags: php, image

i have a webservice that generates an image using 6 different parameters. the process lasts 1 second.
i use the functions ImageCreateFromPNG,ImageCopy and ImageJPEG 
Now i want to speed it up.
the idea is to save the images that were already generated on the server and use them if they are already there by using a name with the 6 parameters.
My question is:
Are there better ways to store the image than saving the jpg-files in a directory on the server ?
(because there are 6^6 (imho 6 to the power of 6) combination possibilities)

bye jogi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the images in good old fashioned file form on the server.

Storing images in a database is not efficient and will likely end up with more pain than it is worth. Store the images in a folder (perhaps even their own little folder) and link to them as per normal. This will allow users to cache the images easily and will be the least impact-heavy on your server.

It will take much less resources to serve a file from a file structure than to query a database, pull the info out, tell the user *what* that data is and do it many times a second/minute/hour/day.

Now, on the other hand, if these are *large* images and take a heck of a lot of space, you might consider generating them dynamically on the fly until you can afford more drive space, but I would suggest the first option if you can.

Lastly (and possibly most importantly - think outside the box), I don't know what these images are like, but you might also consider other methods of creating them. Can they be tiled for example? Rather than storing hundreds of images, can you make those hundreds of images from say 10 segments? You might even be able to send them to the client as they are without joining them up and simply arranging them on the page so that they LOOK like they are one image - but that's just spitballing now.

Comment: +1 for putting across what MOST of the developers believe ;) seriously, image as a blob in dbase is really not what it should be like!

Comment: @KarmicDice in dbase? Does anyone use dbase anymore for web? or Ever did?

Comment: @Sammaye Sadly, yes, they did and probably still do. I recall reading in horror many tutorials about how great it was to store images in a database...

Comment: Oooh dbase is short for database? Lol there is also a database called dbase and thats how I read it :) http://www.dbase.com/ infact the one we use here at times: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to plug but there is one benefical type of storage atm, GridFS.

It is basically a means by which to place data into MongoDB (I am sure other DBs have their own storage mechanism).

The main disadvantage being speed but the main advantage being that it is super easy to shard and distribute your images across your network (and globally). You can even ping them to a CDN for a while to make them even faster.

However I should say this is for bigger sites. Your site sounds like a normal sort of personal blog type project so I would say just store the images in a directory on the server.

However, again, even serving from the directory all the time can become painful so there are certain caching mechanisms you can put in place, for example never expiring headers on the images to ensure the browser caches them for as long as possible. Also cache them within your webserver (like Apache) since I doubt you will wanna serve them directly from the directory you store them in all the time and in the rare occasion you do you would wanna stop malicious people from getting their grubby fingers on your pics so as a precaution (along side server configuration) you would probably serve uncached images from a server-side language or something.

Doing any GD tools usage is extremely load and CPU heavy so you wanna try and do as little as possible because in this case a couple of megs of storage for files is less expensive than a new instance because your CPU bound by uber large images.

There is more advice and what not on Google. For example a straight hit from Google: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html/